# Parsing log files containing NMEA sentences C++

Tags: c++, nmea

I have multiple log files of NMEA sentences that contain geographical positions captured by a camera.
Example of one of the sentences: $GPRMC,100101.000,A,3723.1741,N,00559.5624,W,0.000,0.00,150914,,A*63

My question is, how do you reckon I can start on that? Just need someone to push me to the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Show the code you already have. Then we'll help improve it.

Comment: Quite simple approach would be to copy everything between two '$' to buffer and strsep it by ',' to tokens. But you have to write it yourself

Comment: Pease provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this checksum function in my [GPSReverse](https://www.gpssensordrivers.com/) driver.

```
string chk(const char* data)
    {
    // Assuming data contains a NMEA sentence (check it)
    // Variables for keeping track of data index and checksum 
    const char *datapointer = &data[1];
    char checksum = 0;
    // Loop through entire string, XORing each character to the next 
    while (*datapointer != '\0')
        {
        checksum ^= *datapointer;
        datapointer++;
        }
    // Print out the checksum in ASCII hex nybbles 
    char x[100] = {0};
    sprintf_s(x,100,"%02X",checksum);
    return x;
    }
```

And after that, some append to the NMEA string (say, GGA) :

```
string re = chk(gga.c_str());
gga += "*";
gga += re;
gga += "\r\n";
```

So you can read up to the *, calculate the checksum, and see if it matches the string after the *.

Read more [here](https://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm).

> Each sentence begins with a '$' and ends with a carriage return/line
>   feed sequence and can be no longer than 80 characters of visible text
>   (plus the line terminators). The data is contained within this single
>   line with data items separated by commas. The data itself is just
>   ascii text and may extend over multiple sentences in certain
>   specialized instances but is normally fully contained in one variable
>   length sentence. The data may vary in the amount of precision
>   contained in the message. For example time might be indicated to
>   decimal parts of a second or location may be show with 3 or even 4
>   digits after the decimal point. Programs that read the data should
>   only use the commas to determine the field boundaries and not depend
>   on column positions. There is a provision for a checksum at the end of
>   each sentence which may or may not be checked by the unit that reads
>   the data. The checksum field consists of a '*' and two hex digits
>   representing an 8 bit exclusive OR of all characters between, but not
>   including, the '$' and '*'. A checksum is required on some sentences.

Comment: Thank you sir. That gives me an idea on how I can work around the checksum function of mine.